# XMLHttpRequest.send failing with relative path

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

I'm having difficulty with something probably remedial. I'm developing a website without a server. In doing so, I run into problems when trying to access files via XMLHttpRequest.

As you can see in the example code snippet, I create the variable, open it with a relative path to the desired file, and use the send function.

When I use a relative path that has to traverse up to a parent directory, the send() function fails. However, if I provide a path that is either in the same directory as the webpage or forward in a subfolder of the current webpage directory, i see that the XMLHttpRequest returns successfully. In these successful cases, I can see the data of the test file in request.responseText.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

The only lead I have right now is that there may be a security threat that prevents 'get' requests that traverse up the parent directory.

Thank you.

Code Snippet:

```
function test(){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', "../test.txt", true);
    request.send();//FAILS HERE

    //Get Response
    var response = request.responseText;
}

function test2(){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', "test.txt", true);
    request.send();
    //Get Response
    var response = request.responseText; //SUCCESSFUL
}
```

Comment: Why not install a local server like Apache/IIS? This will resolve your issue. It is likely to browser not allowing this from a security perspective

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the MDN website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same-origin_policy_for_file%3a_URIs), about the Gecko engine and therefore the Firefox browser:

> a file can read another file only if the parent directory of the originating file is an ancestor directory of the target file.

Similar rules exist in other browsers. This is a limitation of the `file:///` protocol. It's there for a very good reason. There's no point trying to break it. The solution is to run a local server on your computer, which isn't even slightly difficult.

To clarify: let's presume that you have a file structure like this:

```
- file1.html
- dir1/
  - file2.html
- dir2/
  - index.html
  - file3.html
  - dir3/
    - file4.html
```

From within `index.html`, you can use Javascript to access `file3.html` and `file4.html`. It cannot access `file1.html` or `file2.html`.

Comment: First, the link is no longer active.
Second, this answer does not help if I want to send a URL containing `a/b/..` to the backend when it is only sent as `a/` because of the `..`

Comment: @ElectRocnic Why do you want to send `a/b/..`? That *means* `a/`: that's how URIs work. (A pity the link is broken: I wonder if the information is outdated now. In any case I think it's irrelevant to your problem as it doesn't sound like you're using a file:/// URI.)

Comment: Yeah I am using a normal http request URL.
I don't want to, to answer you question, but our code allows it and we are seeking a way to pass the `..` through to the backend as is. Even with `%2e%2e` the browser seems to apply path traversal instead of just passing the URL as string.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file in your browser directly using file->open then copy the URL in the address bar.